# Pattern for realizing low priority background threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns

I have a (soft) realtime system which queries some sensor data, does some processing and then waits for the next set of sensor data. The sensor data are read in a receiver thread and put into a queue, so the main thread is "sleeping" (by means of a mutex) until the new data has arrived.

There are other tasks like logging or some long-term calculations in the background to do. These are implemented to run in other threads.

However, it is important that while the main thread processes the sensor data, it should have highest priority which means that the others threads should not consume any CPU resources at all if  possible (currently the background threads cause the main thread to slow down in an unacceptable way.)

According to [Setting thread priority in Linux with Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479945/setting-thread-priority-in-linux-with-boost/1484636#1484636) there is doubt that setting thread priorities will do the job. I am wondering how I can measure which effect setting thread priorities really has? (Platform: Angstrom Linux, ARM PC)

Is there a way to "pause" and "continue" threads completely?

Is there a pattern in C++ to maybe realize the pause/continue on my own? (I might be able to split the background work into small chunks and I could check after every chunk of work if I am allowed to continue, but the question is how big these chunks should be etc.)

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Why not just create the receiver thread and main thread with a very high priority?  When the sensor thread is set ready by the driver, it will run using all of a CPU and when it sets the mutex the main thread will run with all of the CPU, (well once the sensor thread gets back to waiting on its driver).  Failing that, can you move some/all of the sensor data processing to the sensor driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with OS scheduler, not the C++. You need to have a **real** real-time scheduler that will block lower priority threads while the higher priority thread is running.

Most "standard" PC schedulers are not real-time. There's an RT scheduler for Linux - use it. Start with reading about SCHED_RR and SCHED_FIFO, and the `nice` command.

In many systems, you'll have to spawn a **task** (using `fork`) to ensure the nice levels and the RT scheduler are actually effective, you have to read through the manuals of your system and figure out which scheduling modules you have and how are they implemented.

Answer (score 0):

There is no portable way to set the priority in Boost::Thread. The reason is that different OSs will have different API for setting the priority (e.g. Windows and Linux).

The best way to set the priority in a portable way is to write a wrapper to boost::thread with a uniform API that internally gets the thread native_handle, and then uses the OS specific API (for example, in Linux you can use sched_setscheduler()). 
You can see an example here: 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/threadutility/
(code made by a student of mine, look at the svn repository)